# Is there a way to hide empty fields from showing up in the email notification when using EEHarbor Forms?

Tags: ee2, devdemon-forms, eeharbor

I would like to "hide" the empty fields in my admin/user email notifications. Right now it's outputting all of them when I do:

```
{form:fields}
{field:label} : {field:value}
{/form:fields}
```

I've tried using conditionals as well but nothing works.

(The Forms module was previously known as DevDemon Forms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the answer. I had to add quotation marks around the {field:value} conditional. Below is an example.

```
{form:fields}
{if "{field:value}" != ''}
{field:label} : {field:value}
{/if}
{/form:fields}
```